# typescript string interpolation with lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash, interpolation

In my application, I have a H custom component that takes in a header and a subheader as props.

For my header prop, I want to concatenate the lodash expression with a string. See below my code.

```
        <H
          header= `${_.startCase(type)} SomeString`
          subheader= "Lorem ipsum do eiusmod"
        />
```

I have tried the suggestions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals, but maybe because I am using lodash it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for your prop is incorrect:

```
header={`${_.startCase(type)} SomeString`}
```

In React, any prop value that contains *code* must be enclosed in `{}`.

Only constant strings like `prop="a string"` may be passed without a pair of enclosing `{}`. All other values require it*.

---

* Well, there are two special cases.

`children` which is set like the following. Here `children` is something like `<>content</>`.

```
<MyComponent>content</MyComponent>
```

And boolean shorthand props. Here `isCool` is `true`.

```
<MyComponent isCool />
```

Although, if you want to set it to `false` you need curly braces again:

```
<MyComponent isCool={false} />
```